# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Entity framework core, 2 tables in single statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have following 2 classes.

```
public partial class Query
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual QueryGroup QueryGroup { get; set; }
}


public partial class QueryGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Query> Query { get; set; }
}
```

Now these 2 classes are parsed from json. so both Ids are 0, because it is adding (not updating).

When I do below.

```
projectContext.SaveChanges();
```

It gives below error, how to add them both in single statement. or will it require seperate add?

> SqlException: 
>       The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Query_QueryGroup". 
>       The conflict occurred in database "Project", table "dbo.QueryGroup", column 'Id'.

Comment: You must insert QueryGroup and save change first and later insert Query class.

Comment: would you please show us the mapping configuration too?

Comment: Also can you provide json to be parsed?

Comment: you need to insert QueryGroup first then get the id and update n then try savechanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to insert data into **Query** you must have data with ForeignKey in table **QueryGroup**
so you could add data to both tables and then **SaveChanges**

Answer (score 1):

As per the conflict mentioned by you, below is my opinion:

If you have a table **A** having a foreign-key to table **B**, then while adding a record to table **A** the foreign-key value must exist in the table **B**. If the foreign-key value does not exist in table **B** then the above mentioned SqlException occurs.

Hence you need to add data to table **B** first and then table **A**. You can create a single sql transaction for this.